# How to htmlfontify buffer with line number?

Tags: emacs

How to htmlfontify or htmlize a buffer to a html and when open the html, there is linenumber for each line? Currently, it seems htmlfontify-buffer and htmlize-buffer function can not generate the line number even when linum-mode on.

I know that org export can generate line number for blocks if needed. But I don't know how apply it to a whole buffer.

Answer (score 1):

There was a short "discussion" on the gnu.emacs.help group some time ago: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2011-05/msg00283.html

i thereby propose

(shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "nm" (concat (buffer-name) ".html") nil)

matthias

Comment: I found a solution today which is similar to your suggestion. I'm using emacs 24 and I can use command "rectangle-number-lines" (C-x r N) on the whole buffer and then htmlfontify-buffer or htmlize-buffer. But the solution is not perfect. Maybe a javascript is needed.

Comment: Dont worry. A wise frenchman once said: "The perfect is the enemy of the good." See: http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Voltaire